# Laravel groupBy - how to select multiple columns with grouped by one column

Tags: laravel

how to select multiple columns grouped by one column,

Can someone help me with this query?

```
 $data = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('store_id',$id)
        ->select('user_id','username','address','userphoneno', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), DB::raw('SUM(total_amount) as price'))
        ->groupBy('userphoneno')
        ->get();
```

Comment: any select fields that are not in your groupBy, use DB::raw('ANY_VALUE(fieldName)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must disable strict mode for your mysql in config\database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT',
```

---

```
        'strict' => true,   *// **make if false***
```

then this query should work.

```
$data = DB::table('orders')
    ->where('store_id',$id)
    ->select('user_id','username','address','userphoneno', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), DB::raw('SUM(total_amount) as price'))
    ->groupBy('userphoneno')
    ->get();
```